# In eclipse link(eclipselink-2.6.0.v20131019-ef98e5d) Issue with enum

Tags: enums, eclipselink

eclipse link(eclipselink-2.6.0.v20131019-ef98e5d) Issue with enum when Dynamic JAXB convert XML to JSON and viceversa using a multiple schemas

Comment: Can you provide some additional information about your XML schemas?